# How to form the Json value for the given elastic search search query in node js

Tags: json, node.js, elasticsearch

Hi I'm new in node js I was created the search query in elastic search as follows:

```
   {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "healthy"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "status": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "associatedUserIds": 248
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "createrFriendsId": 248
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "communityMembers": 248
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the filter fields are changed dynamically by based on user request.I had a difficult to form the JSON variable for above query .Is anyone guide me to achive this?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your request you can modify your "must" by pushing into the array.
You can do that by:

```
json.query.bool.must.push({
    "foo": {
        "bar": "baz"
    }
});
```

The above code is just pushing another element into the array "must".